# What's the difference between these two in kotlin class declaration?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
class WordRepository(private val wordDao: WordDao) {
    suspend fun insertWord(word: Word) = wordDao.insert(word)
}
```

```
class WordRepository(wordDao: WordDao) {
    suspend fun insertWord(word: Word) = wordDao.insert(word)
}
```

The second snippet gives error: "wordDao is not defined". I could really use some insight on this matter, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference here is the `val` word in the class parameters part, without it (second one) it is just a parameter of the constructor, which cannot be accessed outside of it. With this word, the first one, you are actually doing something like:

```
class WordRepository(inputWordDao: WordDao) {

    // during constructor, input parameter will be stored to (private) propety
    private val wordDao = inputWordDao

    // this class method is accessing the stored property, not the constructor parameter
    suspend fun insertWord(word: Word) = wordDao.insert(word)
}
```

Furthermore, the same could be written as

```
class SecondWordRepository(inputWordDao: WordDao) {

    // define private property
    private val wordDao: WordDao

    // during constructor, assign the parameter to the property
    init {
        wordDao = inputWordDao
    }

    // this class method is accessing the stored property, not the constructor parameter
    suspend fun insertWord(word: Word) = wordDao.insert(word)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think the difference between propety and parameter is the key.  In your answer  it says "Property is explicitly assigned to parameter wordDao, so it can be declared directly in constructor "

Answer (score -1):

**In the first class:**
The wordDao parameter is declared as a private property (private val). This means that it can only be accessed within the class WordRepository.

**In the second class:**
The wordDao parameter is not marked as private, so it can be accessed from outside the class.

The difference between these two versions is the visibility of the wordDao parameter. In the first version, it's private and accessible only within the class, while in the second version, it's accessible from outside the class as well.